# Android background services alternative on Oreo

Tags: android

I want to create a background only app (no activities, no launcher icon, etc...), since I'm relatively new to Android, I don't know what to use. I saw there was the [background services](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service) but it seems to be depreciated with Android API 26+ (Oreo).

So, what is the preferred way to do this now?

In case I have root access, is it possible to do it?

Comment: "I want to create a background only app (no activities, no launcher icon, etc...)" -- unless you are building your own firmware, or your app is really a plugin for another app, your app would never run, on Android 3.2+. "what is the preferred way to do this now?" -- don't create a background-only app.

Comment: @CommonsWare When I look on the app list in the settings, I saw some apps that start at boot and are just backgrounds apps so it should be possible to do that on recent Android versions.

Comment: Those apps are either part of the firmware (or extensions from it delivered by Google through the Play Store), or they have activities. Or, there is a new security flaw in Android that these apps are exploiting.

Comment: @CommonsWare So what about the apps like keyloggers that say they're invisible?

Answer (score 1):

Even though background services are restricted in Oreo and beyond, foreground services are still supported.  If you want to create an app with no activities, using a foreground service that starts on boot is a valid option.

Comment: Will it have an icon or anything like that?

Comment: Foreground services are required to display an ongoing notification containing an icon in the notification bar.  This displays differently across different versions of Android.  But it's there to remind the user that your app is running.  And the app will also display under Settings->Apps.  But you will not be required to show up in the launcher.  All that being said, having at least one activity to allow the user to enable/disable the service would not be a bad idea but it's not required.

Comment: Let's say that the user choose to block all notifications for this app in the settings, will the app still start at boot time?

Comment: By the way, say I have root access, is it possible to hide everything?

Comment: If the user blocked the visibility of the ongoing notification, that should not impact the boot time starting of the service.  As far as root access, I'm not sure if that makes it possible to hide stuff even further.